# Creating a method to execute based off instance?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Is there such a thing as creating a method in a class to do something based off one of the populated fields? Kind of like a static method.

Just trying to create my own *Ping()* Method but, would like it to just use the `ComputerName` property already populated.

```
Class Device {
    
    [string]$ComputerName
    [string]$Status
    [string]$Manufacturer
    [string]$Model
    [string]$SerialNumber

    [Void]Ping($ComputerName) {
        
        $Echo_Reply = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet

        $this.Status = $Echo_Reply

    }

}
```

So if I instantiate it, assign a computer name to the property, can I use my *Ping()* method just as is without referring to it, to actually ping?

- `$Device = [device]::new()`
- `$Device.ComputerName = 'ComputerOne'`

Could I just use my method to ping it: `$Device.Ping()`, instead of referencing it `$Device.Ping('ComputerOne')`.

Comment: I've not really done much (/ anything) with classes in PowerShell, but the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.1#example-simple-class-with-properties-and-methods suggests ```$this.ComputerName``` is the syntax you're looking for to read a property value, just like you've done with ```$this.Status``` to set one.

Comment: Hello, I had the same thought process in which I did try that. Just throws an *overload* exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **You're looking for an *instance* method**, not a *static* one, i.e. one that can implicitly operate on the specific state of an instance of the [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) at hand.
- What the code in your question defines *is* an instance method, and, as [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out, you must **use `$this.<property-name>` to refer to an instance's properties from inside an instance method**, so your method can be redefined to:

  ```sh
  [void] Ping() {        
    $this.Status = Test-Connection -ComputerName $this.ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet
  }
  ```
- **Pitfall**, as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.7:

  - If, after defining your `class` *directly* in your script, you try to *redefine* it later *in the same script* via [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) (`. <script>`), the redefinition is *quietly ignored*.

    - Arguably, such a redefinition in what is effectively the *same* scope should be *prevented* altogether, as is already the case if you try to redefine the same class *directly* in a given scope.
    - See [GitHub issue #8767](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8767)
  - **When in doubt, start a *new session* to ensure that the *latest* definition of your class takes effect**.